# LC4VF, Summer 2016: The $Lightning.use function works in Developer Org but gets 500 Error in Sandbox

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, summer-16

How do I eliminate or work around a 500 error preventing me from using Lightning components on a VisualForce page in a sandbox? Identical code works in a dev org but fails in a sandbox.

**Note:** In the sandbox I used, the "My Domain" feature is in a "Ready for Testing but Hidden from Users" state, whereas in the dev org I used, the "My Domain" feature is in a fully deployed state.

Only mentioning My Domain for good measure, since [this document](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_lightning_cruc.htm) says:

> Finally, you don’t need to enable My Domain to use Lightning
>   components in the following contexts.
>
> - Lightning components with Communities in Community Builder
> - Lightning Components for Visualforce

Copious details below.

## Inputs

Sample code taken verbatim from [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm?search_text=visualforce).

### lcvfTest.app

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
    <aura:dependency resource="ui:button"/>
</aura:application>
```

### lcvfTest.vfp

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:lcvfTest", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("ui:button",
          { label : "Press Me!" },
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
          });
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

## Results

Dev org succeeded but Sandbox failed.

### Dev Org

Renders a button, just as described in the documentation.

### Sandbox Org

No Button is rendered. The browser's debug console reveals a request which fails with a 500 error.

(**Note:** In the following output, hash-like values in the "loaded" object were replaced with fictitious ones, since I do not know whether the hashes contain private information. Custom domain values are also fictitious. The "fwid" values are not fictitious.)

The URL of the request which triggered a 500 error was:

```
https://my-custom-domain--my-sandbox-name.cs2.my.salesforce.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22c%3AlcvfTest%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22HARM87fxppWmsEY_Ve9awQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fc%3AlcvfTest%22%3A%22N7gJLRFbk4dlneywPZJt2f%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22YN%22%7D/inline.js
```

Opening this URL in its own browser tab yields the following content (indentation added by me):

```
aura.error(
{
    "exceptionEvent":true,
    "event": {
        "descriptor":"markup://aura:clientOutOfSync",
        "eventDef": {
            "s":1,
            "v": {
                "descriptor":"markup://aura:clientOutOfSync",
                "type":"APPLICATION",
                "superDef": {
                    "s":2,
                    "v": {
                        "descriptor":"markup://aura:applicationEvent",
                        "type":"APPLICATION",
                        "xs":"G",
                        "attributes":{}
                    }
                },
                "attributes":{}
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultHandler":"function() {$A.clientService.setOutdated()}"
});
```

The large URL-encoded portion of the URL above decodes to this (indentation added by me):

```
{
    "mode":"PROD",
    "app":"c:lcvfTest",
    "fwuid":"HARM87fxppWmsEY_Ve9awQ",
    "loaded":
    {
        "APPLICATION@markup://c:lcvfTest":"N7gJLRFbk4dlneywPZJt2f"
    },
    "requestedLocales":["en_US","en"],
    "ls":"YN"
}
```

## Environments Tested

Attempted some additional setups other than those above. Here is a full list of environments tested (including the above), with results:

1. *Failed:* A Sandbox (on cs2) for a Summer 2016 Enterprise org, created
   before June 11. My Domain in a Testing phase of deployment.
2. *Failed:* Another Sandbox (on cs44) for org #1, created on July 19. My Domain in a testing phase of deployment.
3. *Succeeded:* A Developer Edition org. My Domain fully deployed.
4. *Succeeded:* Another Developer Edition org. My Domain fully deployed.
5. *Succeeded:* A sandbox for an Unlimited Edition org, unrelated to org #1 and created before June 11. My Domain fully deployed.

## Possible Stack Trace

While I do not know how to access a server-side exception log for the Aura framework, I have attempted to piece together a stack trace by manually inspecting the [Aura source code from github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/). The result of my attempt is as follows:

1. [AuraResourceServlet.doGet: Line 124](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura/src/main/java/org/auraframework/http/AuraResourceServlet.java#L124)
2. [TemplateResource.write: Line 68](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura/src/main/java/org/auraframework/http/resource/TemplateResource.java#L68)
3. [TemplateResource.internalWrite: Line 87](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura/src/main/java/org/auraframework/http/resource/TemplateResource.java#L87)
4. [DefinitionServiceImpl.updateLoaded: Line 209](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/java/org/auraframework/impl/DefinitionServiceImpl.java#L209)

Comment: Determined that "fwid" does not contain personal information but a hash of all javascript in the framework. Thus, replaced the fictional value in this post with the real value. In the process, decided that [this code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/java/org/auraframework/impl/adapter/ConfigAdapterImpl.java#L167-L172) in the framework looks suspect.

Comment: Error seems to originate from [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/java/org/auraframework/impl/DefinitionServiceImpl.java#L209), although I know of no way to verify that this is indeed the ClientOutOfSyncException being thrown. If I follow the code correctly, it may have something to do with the [MasterDefRegistryImpl](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/java/org/auraframework/impl/system/MasterDefRegistryImpl.java) having the wrong uid for the APPLICATION.